# column of read count in sharepoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-list

Scenario simple I have a list contains books, each item refers a book in list and each item has **ReadCount** column, whenever a user click details(imagine that there is a detail button of the book) and reads detail of a book readcount will be increment by 1 of related book item

how is it done in SP by efficient way ?

Comment: What do you mean by "click details"? Is this a button, a link in the list view? Does this take the user to the Display Form of the list?

Comment: bro it doenst matter, the question is how can I increment a value of item for each request

Comment: When you ask something and especially how to do something efficiently, it is imperative that you explain your scenario in more detail. There might be some events that get triggered when the click occurs, so you may be able to bind into those events to develop your counter. If you are unwilling to provide more details, people may not be able to answer your question, at least I cannot at the moment. So far I can tell you that there is no out-of-the-box solution for having a item views counter.

Answer (score 0):

We didn`t find an out of the box solution and implemented this scenario using following approach.

- Added client side script to the details page.
- On page load this script updates list item column to increment the exisitng value.
- This approach is flexible to log complete user details along with count increment.

I can help if you need additional details on this approach.

Comment: yes please can you eloborate